# Generate Sum of Occurrence of an action in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need assistance on how to generate the sum of occurrence of an exception from an entries that is capture daily on a weekly basis group by the offenders. take a look at my code which works for the offender but summing the offence totally instead of summing it for individual offender.

```
     <tr>
     <th>S/N</th>
     <th>NAME</th>
     <th>STAFF ID</th>
     <th>ABS</th>
     <th>BRK</th>
     <th>BV</th>
     <th>DUI</th>
     <th>OS</th>
     <th>OTH</th>
     <th>Details of Other Offences</th>
     </tr>
<?php 
    $get = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tab_incidence WHERE mainloc='$loc' AND cast(created_at as date) BETWEEN '$td1' AND '$td2' AND weekno='$wk' AND team='$tm'  GROUP BY op ORDER BY fltno");
    $c=0;$sumAbs=0;$sBrk=0;$sBv=0;$sDui=0;$sOs=0;$sOth=0;
    while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($get)){
    $c++;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>". $c."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>".$rw['op']."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>".$rw['staffno']."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>" .($rw['details']=='ABS'?$sumAbs=$sumAbs+1:'0')."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>". ($rw['details']=='BRK'?$sBrk=$sBrk+1:'0')."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>". ($rw['details']=='BV'?$sBv=$sBv+1:'0')."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>". ($rw['details']=='DUI'?$sDui=$sDui+1:'0')."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>". ($rw['details']=='OS'?$sOs=$sOs+1:'0')."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>". ($rw['details']=='OTH'?$sOth=$sOth+1:'0')."</td>";
    echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'>". $rw['svalcom']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     };}?>
```

I wantit to be able to sum each offence for each staff based on the weekno which is stored as week1, week2, week3. Note in each week, i have a record for each day that the offence is committed which will fall into week1 or 2 or 3 or 4.Any clue or assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: It's best to group by staff id not name since multiple staff may share the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one: Find the staff who made any incident within a certain date (the week you are looking for)

```
SELECT distinct(staffno) as staff FROM tab_incidence WHERE mainloc='$loc' AND cast(created_at as date) BETWEEN '$td1' AND '$td2' AND weekno='$wk' AND team='$tm'
```

Step 2: Loop the result

```
 while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($get)){ // Pass by every staff

 // Query  for ABS is 
  SELECT count(id) as number FROM tab_incidence WHERE mainloc='$loc' AND cast(created_at as date) BETWEEN '$td1' AND '$td2' AND weekno='$wk' AND staffno='$rw["staff"]' AND details = 'ABS' // This will return the number of ABS offense per staff

}
```

Each type would require a query.

Comment: will the loop enable me to echo all as a report?

Comment: You can use multi dimensional arrays (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) inside the loops to fill the data. First dimension would be staff number, Second one would be offense type.

When the loop is over you can display the data as you please

Comment: I try the code above, with the select count(id) assigning it to a variable  inside the loop for each of the offence. When I  echo the variable, i get error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string. pls what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try it for one offense first to test it out. Also replace staffno='$rw["staff"]' with staffno=" .$rw['staff']. "

Comment: Khalili: it works by running the code an assign it to a variable,then i fetch it using mysqli_fetch_array($query). echo using $ab['ab']; Thanks a million